# Problems with converting BSTR to float

Tags: com, implicit-conversion, bstr

I'm trying to convert BSTR to float with:

```
wcstod(data, NULL)
```

The problem is that this function works ok if data = 239.78, but i receive them in this format **data = 239,78**.

```
CComBSTR data = SysAllocString(L"239,78");
cout<<wcstod(data,NUll)<<endl;
```

Output of this code is 239.

Anyone could help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [wcstod_l](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab.aspx) instead and pass the locale you need as the 3rd argument, so the ',' is understood and parsed properly. Something like this:

```
_locale_t fr = _create_locale(LC_ALL, "fr-FR"); // french locale
CComBSTR data = SysAllocString(L"239,78");
cout<<wcstod_l(data, NULL, fr)<<endl;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!
Sorry, i can't vote up due to my low reputation.